# Can a "Software raid" be set up to be read as a native bios "fakeraid"?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, raid

I was wondering if there is any means or software that is capable of drawing up a raid, through a software method, in which I can stuff into a machine. to install windows on.

I only have 2 drives I can work with, and ill have to shimmy 800Gigs+ of data to make it work, but I see it as less costly than buying another drive (I wish blueray disks were cheaper)

I also need to know if a raid0 can be set up to be inflatable/growable whats the word im missing.

Comment: Any raid controller worth it's salt can grow a RAID 0 or RAID 1 or RAID 5 array.

Comment: Yes, but they require(or mine does) naked disks. or it wont even look at the partitionless 70% of the drive... which is gay.

Comment: Softraid shouldn't care, you could probably tell it to make a raid out of several files. FakeRAID would have that limitation. It's always good to just use drives that are all the same size anyways.